How to programmatically stop and start a console application?
I have a console application written in C# that I plan to deploy to Azure. I need to be able to programmatically control its execution — specifically, start and stop the app using code (c#).
Any suggestion?
Since I am new to deploying console applications in Azure, I don’t have any prior knowledge or experience.

How are you planning to "deploy" it? What is going to be hosted in?

Do you really want to start/stop the entire app or just control if it is performing a specific action?

Why not export the functionality of the CLI as a DLL instead?

Does your application support CTRL+C to stop it?  That's how Azure will call your app to stop it.
If you use a background task, or otherwise cancellable tasks, then it should exit cleanly.
For example:
static async Task Main()
{
    await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().RunConsoleAsync();
}

Will automatically support CTRL+C to exit.

"That's how Azure will call your app to stop it" there's a lot of different ways to run code in Azure. How that platform chooses to stop the app very depends on said platform.

Of the 15 different ways I've seen, they all start with sending sigterm (CTRL-C) as a first attempt.  Even on Windows platforms.

I have more info now, I explain it better.

Now, I have more info, I have a console application deployed on Azure(I have a azure function in it ), and it is called by an external service. The flow is as follows:
The external service triggers the console application.
The console application "wakes up", performs a task, and returns a success or failure response.
Once the task is completed, the application should "shut down" automatically to save resources.
What is the best way to implement this ?

@Neil Then why do you have a console application at all if you can just trigger the code inside the Azure Function?

Could you explain that, how I can do that? please.

The function is called once a month

Azure will automatically start and stop your [Function] whenever it is needed.   I would still recommend supporting the ctrl+C method, so that your console app shuts down cleanly, but Azure will still handle the start and stop.  I presume you have read this page, or your code is very similar? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

@DavidG  ALL .NET apps are console apps these days.  Azure Functions just have methods marked with special attributes so that Azure knows what to call after start up, depending on the trigger.

@Neil I know how they work, I write them for a living. My question still remains.

You can use Process.start to call a program. See below to Kill a process.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start().
Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileName);

foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever"))
{
    process.Kill();
}


How would this be able to start/stop an application running in Azure?
